# In Snowflake, how do I CAST CURRENT_TIMESTAMP up to the minute only?

Tags: timestamp, cast, snowflake

In Snowflake, how do I CAST CURRENT_TIMESTAMP up to the minute only. I don't want seconds, milliseconds, or timezone included in my result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [TO_CHAR or TO_VARCHAR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_char).

Query,

```
select to_char(current_timestamp(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as new_dt;
```